# Create AWS EC2 instance with specific flavour using jclouds and Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jclouds

I recently installed jclouds to use with eclipse to create a project in java to communicate with aws-ec2. Does anyone know if there is a way to create an instance using  "instance flavours". I would appreciate it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this in jclouds. The easiest is just to use the `hardwareId` property when creating a node. This is a String whose value is the flavour of VM you wish to create, so `m1.xlarge` or `m3.medium` etc. Specify it as follows.

```
Template template = computeService.templateBuilder()
        .hardwareId(InstanceType.M1_MEDIUM);
nodes = computeService.createNodesInGroup("groupname", 1, template);
```

You can also just specify minumum RAM and CPU settings in the template, and let jclouds choose the hardware flavour itself, like this.

```
Template template = computeService.templateBuilder()
        .minCores(2.0d)
        .minRam(2048);
```